# Why is "00:00:00" seen as being the same thing as NULL in MYSQL Time field?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a mysql field called "time_of_birth" that is definitely set to NULL.

I have a PHP check on that field like this:

```
if ($row['time_of_birth'] !== "00:00:00") {
//do this stuff
} else {
//do something else
}
```

For that field that is definitely set to NULL, it's doing the "do this stuff".  Isn't NULL different than "00:00:00"?  I would expect it to do "do something else" because it's not exactly equal to "00:00:00".

What am I missing here?

Comment: `NULL !== "00:00:00"` is `true`, so the result is expected. Have you accidentally mixed things up in your question, or is this a factual representation of your actual code? If so, it works as expected. `!==` is the stricter comparison version of `!=`, both meaning **not** equal to, and since `NULL` is not equal to `"00:00:00"`, it's working a expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I just confused myself over something that should be so simple.  Been a late night, need to get rest and start again fresh tomorrow. Thanks for helping me think about it differently

Comment: We've all been there and will probably be there sometime again. Good night. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is doing it correctly. It is not seeing null as equal to '00:00:00' `!==` is a proof that it is not seeing it as same and entering that block.